# SetInterval is hogging up resources- alternatives the Node.js way

Tags: node.js

Below is a simple function that reports the time as well as system resources 100 times a second:

```
var util = require('util');

function report(){
    console.log(new Date());
    console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
}

setInterval(report,10);
```

*Sure, the example isn't the most practical- more so for illustrative purposes*

It works- however the memory allocation goes **up and up and up**. From my understanding, this isn't a memory leak- but rather the natural behavior of Javascript. This is due to the function, or record of performed functions are being added to the heap every time setInterval is called. And it will do this as long as the process is alive.

**So here's the question:**

Is there a better way to achieve the same output, but more efficiently?

Comment: Hmm... to the best of my knowledge the growing memory usage is *not* just the "natural behavior of JavaScript".  You may have discovered a memory leak in `process.memoryUsage()` or, less likely, `util.inspect()`.  What kind of memory consumption are we talking about here, though?  It could just be that it's not being reclaimed if its under a certain threshold.

Comment: Also, what version of Node.js?

Comment: @jmar777 Just installed the latest version- whatever that is. Garbage collection does work, as I see the resources being returned regularly after amount of time. However, leave it run for a few hours...aye aye aye....

Comment: Rephrase: MOST of resources are being returned. Overall memory trends upward after garbage collection. Resources visualized on a graph would resemble that of an uphill sawtooth pattern.

Comment: Interesting... I'd raise this in the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/nodejs) as it smells memory-leakish to me.